# Rails: Submit form modal for confirming submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, bootstrap-modal

So I have a form that needs to have a disclaimer modal when it is clicked. It is like a long disclaimer so it would do better to be in a modal than on the form page. So the user clicks a button on the form which triggers the modal. Then from the modal, there is the "Submit form" button that would actually do the submission.

How is this possible because the way I have it now, the submit button does nothing when clicked. Is it possible to do a normal form submit in this situation (from a modal)? Is there javascript I can use to make this work?

```
<%= form_for [:client, Reportapproval.new], :validate => true do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.hidden_field :blah, :value => current_client.name %>
  </div>
  <div class="block-inline">
    <label>Blah Blah</label><br>
     <%= f.select :client... %>   
  </div>
  <%= f.text_field :client... %>
    <label>
      <%= f.hidden_field :client... %>
    </label>
  <div class="text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#client_disclaimer_modal">
        Request a report from this renter
      </button> <!--- This button opens the modal--->
  </div>

<!-- Disclaimer Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="clent_disclaimer_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Client Disclaimer Agreement</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <strong>NOTICE...<br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= f.submit "Agree & Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 
<br /> 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the `<button type='submit'>` is in the `<form>`, the code you presented above should work perfectly. Make sure that whatever JS is controlling the modal is not moving the modal markup to a different place in the DOM (i.e. moving it to be a direct descendent of the `body` tag).

Comment: So in my modal I am submiting thru a rails action ````<%= f.submit "Agree & Submit", class: 'btn btn-default' %>```` that wont work?

Comment: It still should work. That `f.submit` still generates a proper submit button. Have you tested this and confirmed it is not working?

Comment: I tested it the way it is above as well as ````<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Agree & Submit</button>```` No bueno, still does nothing when I click submit

Comment: I even tried closing the form with ````</form>```` within the modal. Still no go.

Comment: Looking at the 2nd part of your answer I am using a twitter bootstrap modal would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I also had a swell time figuring this out:

**Here's how I did me**:

According to the official [Rails Guides](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to-label-Data+attributes), you can use custom data attributes using the `:data` option:

```
<%= form.submit  'Submit Application', data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

You just have a typo in your code. :)

Change "clent_disclaimer_modal" to "client_disclaimer_modal". Verified all works as expected with this update in place.